# NSLocale - finding CountryCode and then using this to deploy code

Tags: iphone, ios, locale, nslocale

I am stumped as to why this code isn't working as per the comment below:

```
NSString *countryCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSLog(@"Country Code: %@", countryCode);

if (countryCode == @"US") {
    NSLog(@"Country is USA"); // Does not execute since the if does not pass
}
```

The locale is en_US therefore the country code is US. Everything is correct on that part of things. What am I doing wrong, and how do I get "Country is USA" to display?

Thank you!

*Testing on iOS 5.1 and 6.0, same result*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings cannot be compared using the `==` operator, try using `isEqualToString:` instead:

```
NSString *countryCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSLog(@"Country Code: %@", countryCode);

if ([countryCode isEqualToString: @"NL"]) {
    NSLog(@"Country is NL");
}
```

Used `NL` since I'm in the Netherlands :)

Comment: Wow, cannot believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You must use the `isEqualToString:` method to compare the contents two strings. The `==` operator tests for equality of the two pointers and therefore returns 0.